# Calculate the flux of $F=(3xy^2,3x^2y,z^3),$ $ S$ the sphere of radio 1.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Calculate the flux  of $F=(3xy^2,3x^2y,z^3),$ $ S$ the sphere of radius 1.

I have done $\iint F\cdot n dS= \frac{12\pi}5$

I am not sure about of that result because when I try to solve this by using the Divergence Theorem I get another value:

$$\iint_S\vec F\cdot \vec ndS=\iiint_V\nabla\cdot \vec FdV=3\iiint_V(x^2+y^2+z^2)dV$$
Then, since S is the sphere of radius 1 $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$
$$=3\iiint_VdV=3(\frac{4\pi}{3})=4\pi$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\iint_S\vec F\cdot \vec ndS=\iiint_V\nabla\cdot \vec FdV=3\iiint_V(x^2+y^2+z^2)dV$$
$$=3\iiint_Vr^2dV=3\int_0^14\pi r^4dr=\frac{12}{5}\pi$$

Comment: but since S is the sphere of radio 1 x2+y2+z2=1, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexTurner It's equal to 1 on the surface of the sphere, but in this case you have to integrate $x^2+y^2+z^2$ over the whole volume of the sphere, so its not always 1.

Comment: @AlexTurner Hope you have understood the argument :)

Comment: Yes, I understood. Thanks

Comment: @AlexTurner You are welcome!